# Tensor Product of a Bra and a Ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus

What does one get if the take the tensor product of a bra and a ket, for instance, $\langle\uparrow \rvert \otimes \lvert \downarrow\rangle$?

What I mean it, what is this object? What does it act on? Or does it get acted on? Is it meaningful, like the tensor product of two kets is, etc?

Comment: Also what is the standard LaTeX for bra-ket notation?

Comment: Um...you get the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of the bra and the ket? I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry. Let me clarify.

Comment: Can you perform that tensor product?

Comment: @KyleKanos It just gives me a matrix, right? I don't know how to texify matrices.

Comment: I know $|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|$ gives a tensor, but writing it the other way, $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle$ denotes the [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: @Anthony see [these short, but very useful, set of notes](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/tensorproduct.pdf)

Comment: @KyleKanos I know that is an inner product, I was asking about a tensor product written that way.

Comment: @Hunter, I don't think that answers my question. I think what I wrote is *something* I just don't know what it'd be useful for.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, I don't think it makes sense. I mean, they're different types of objects... Right?

Comment: This type of question arises often when people are introduced to tensor products of vectors spaces in a physics context without taking a formal math class.  (I know, because I had the same confusion.)  I'll try to answer below.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I haven't really seen the mathematical definition of a tensor product.

Comment: FYI, the issue with Hunter's notes is that they don't define covectors.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the corresponding Hilbert space, then $\langle \uparrow | \otimes |\downarrow \rangle \in \mathcal{H}^\star \otimes \mathcal{H}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The confusion is coming from the fact that you're thinking in terms of the bra-ket physics notation without understanding how the underlying vector spaces are constructed.

"Kets" are *vectors* in a vector space, i.e. a set of objects on which vector-vector addition and vector-scalar multiplication is defined (for some field of scalars).  "Bra"s are *covectors*, aka *one-forms*, defined as linear functions from a vector space to its field of scalars.  They *also* form a vector space, and they exist *even if we don't define an inner product* on the set of kets.

Since the space of bras is a vector space, it can be tensored with another vector space such as the space of kets.  This is defined just like any other [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces) of two vector spaces (which is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), equipped with an intuitive definition of addition and multiplication).  You could write this down in two equivalent ways: $\vert{\uparrow}\rangle \otimes \langle{\downarrow}\vert$ or $\langle{\downarrow}\vert \otimes \vert{\uparrow}\rangle$.  They are structurally the same thing, just with a different convention for the ordering.  (Likewise, coordinates in 3D can be ordered $(x,y,z)$ or $(z,y,x)$ without changing anything.)

The first case is often abbreviated $\vert{\uparrow}\rangle \langle{\downarrow}\vert$ since there's no risk of confusing it with anything else. (Of course, that notation is a bit dangerous since it suggest we have a way of associating a bra $\langle x \vert$ with every ket $\vert x \rangle $, but that would be a mistake because we haven't defined an inner product.)

On the other hand, if you tried to write the second case as $\langle{\downarrow}\vert \vert{\uparrow}\rangle$ or $\langle{\downarrow}\vert{\uparrow}\rangle$, it could be misinterpreted as letting the bra (which is a linear functional from the space of kets to the scalars) act on the ket, which produces a scalar.  That's a very different mathematical object.  If the bras and kets have vector space dimension $N$, then the object  $\langle{\downarrow}\vert{\uparrow}\rangle$ has dimension 1 while the object  $\langle{\downarrow}\vert \otimes \vert{\uparrow}\rangle$ has dimension $N^2$.

Comment: So in some respect, the tensor product of two spaces is the *unique* linear map from the two? And my confusion is just notational?

Comment: Not quite, assuming I'm understanding you correctly.  The tensor product of two vector spaces is another vector space.  The members of this new, larger space *aren't* yet a linear map to scalars until you either (1) define an inner product (in which case the large vectors can map themselves to scalars) or (2) define a space of large covectors (in which case the vectors map covectors to scalars, and the covectors map vectors to scalars).  Remember, a covector *literally is* a linear map from a vector space to the scalars.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean a linear map to scalars, I'm not quite sure what I meant though. I've just heard that tensor products are a way to linearize multilinear maps, or something like that. In any case though, the ordering doesn't matter on the bra's and ket's, it's just notational?

Comment: Yes, the choice of order is just notation.

Comment: @Anthony The tensor product of two vector spaces $X,Y$ is the most general space $T = X\otimes Y$ such that every bilinear map $X \times Y \to Z$ corresponds to a unique linear map $X\otimes Y \to Z$.

Comment: When you abbreviate it as $|\uparrow \rangle \langle\downarrow|$, do you mean here that the tensor product and the outer product are the same things?

Comment: @Nour Yes. The outer product is just a  name for the tensor product in the special case of taking the tensor product of two coordinate vectors (typically in finite dimensions).